# Problema con NOT EXISTS en SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

Tengo un problema con una consulta en SQL. Tengo mi tabla `pedidos` que tiene los campos `numero pedido`, `fecha recepción` y `código cliente` y necesito generar un listado de los clientes que no han realizado pedidos en un período determinado y se me ocurrió hacerlo así :

```
SELECT cod_cli
 FROM pedidos
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT cod_cli
             FROM pedidos
             WHERE fec_rep>20140809 AND fec_rep<20141010)
```

Pero cuando le doy continuar, me arroja este error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT cod_cli
   FROM pedidos
   WHERE fec_rep>20140809 AND fec_rep<2' at line 3
```

¿Cual es el error?

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta tiene 2 problemas:

1. No encontrará todos los clientes que no han hecho pedidos, pues te basas en la tabla de pedidos misma y debieras basarte en la tabla de clientes. (en la forma que lo haces no encontraría los clientes que nunca han hecho un pedido y te listaría cada clientes tantas veces como pedidos haya realizado).
2. El error de sintaxis es porque las fechas deben pasarse como parámetros (que es lo recomendado) o bien como constantes literales (menos recomendado). Si decides pasarla como literal, el formato de fecha adecuado dependerá del motor de base de datos que estés utilizando, y en ocasiones de la manera en que esté configurado.

Tomando en cuenta esto y suponiendo que el campo que relaciona la tabla clientes y pedidos es cod_cli, y que tu motor reconocerá la fecha en formato ISO (YYYYMMDD) la consulta debiera quedar algo así:

```
SELECT c.cod_cli
  FROM clientes c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT 1
              FROM pedidos p
             WHERE p.cod_cli = c.cod_cli
               and p.fec_rep between '20140809' and '20141010')
```

Comment: resulta que la  tabla pedidos contiene : numero pedido, fecha recepción y código cliente, es decir, el pedido correspondiente a cada cliente, no se si es podrá cambiar algo

Comment: @Sebastian, no tienes una tabla de clientes?

Comment: si si existe la tabla clientes

Comment: Si existe la tabla de clientes, la solución es como te digo. De otra forma, no vas a obtener los clientes que nunca han hecho un pedido.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, como dice la respuesta anterior, deberías basarte en la tabla de clientes.

¿Podrías darnos más información de tu base de datos? ¿Existe la tabla clientes?

Basándome en suposiciones, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
select c.cod_cli
FROM clientes c
left join (
    select cod_cli from pedidos
    where p.fec_rep>20140809 AND p.fec_rep<20141010) p
on c.cod_cli = p.cod_cli where p.cod_cli = null
```

De esta manera seleccionas los clientes de la tabla 'clientes' que no aparecen en la tabla 'pedidos' durante las fechas indicadas.

Comment: Hola. No entiendo el uso de `to_char` y que usas el resultado de la función para compararlo a un valor numérico. De todas formas, parece que OP está usando MariaDB, de modo que no creo que exista una función `to_char`.

Comment: Tienes razón, no ví ese detalle. Edito la respuesta.